# Find min/max/average memory used by pod using promethus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to find min/max/average memory consumed by particular pod over a time inteval.

Currently I am using

```
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="test", pod="test1", container!="POD", container!=""}) by (container)

Output -> test1 = 9217675264
```

For report purpose, I need to find what the min/peak memory used by pod over a time interval ( 6h)
and average too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a range vector (add an `[interval]` to a metric name/selector) and an [aggregation-over-time function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time):

```
min_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{}[6h])
max_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{}[6h])
avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{}[6h])
```

Comment: Thanks . and do we have way to convert output value to say GB ? Right now , I am getting 8944175025 as ouput ( Which means 8.9GB ?)

Comment: @pythonhmmm there is no 'magic' function for that but you can use math: `avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{}[6h])/(2^30)`

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Can I reduce/filter the output. Currently I get  {container="cont1",endpoint="http",instance=":8080",job="kube-state-metrics",namespace="test",node="node_name",pod="pod_name",service="monitoring-kube-state-metrics"} and value . Is it possible just to get  { pod_name : value } something similar.

Comment: @pythonhmmm `sum by(pod_name) (min_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{}[6h]))` that'll result in `{pod_name="some_name"} 123`. That's probably the closest I can think of to what you've requested. If you want something like json, consider using [api](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/).